# when is class loaded by JVM?

Tags: java, memory-management, jvm, classloader

Say i start the web server(or any other java process), will all the class (metadata like class definition) be loaded at server/process startup even before
they are used anywhere in the system or they are loaded at runtime i.e. only while object is getting created or import statement is encountered?

This question is for jdk 8 and jdk 6

Comment: See the [Java Virtual Machine Specification #5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in bytecode, there are no **import** statements. Bytecode simply uses fully qualified names all over the place.

Then, the default behavior of most JVMs is to do "lazy" loading of classes. Meaning: when you load class A, the JVM will only load those classes that are required to run all the static intializers for A.

So, if A "uses" B and C; then B, C are only loaded when the JVM executes code that needs B resp. C to be loaded.

When writing your **own** class loader, you could of course do things differently.

Comment: so they are loaded at runtime as and when they are referenced. Right ?

Comment: Yes, that would be a correct way of saying what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

see [Class loading architecture](http://www2.sys-con.com/itsg/virtualcd/Java/archives/0808/chaudhri/index.html)

Here are the relevant lines in context of your question

> ClassLoaders are architected so that at start-up the JVM doesn't need
>   to know anything about the classes that will be loaded at runtime.
>
> Initially when a JVM starts up, nothing is loaded into it. The class
>   file of the program being executed is loaded first and then other
>   classes and interfaces are loaded as they get referenced in the
>   bytecode being executed.

Answer (score 0):

> JVM does lazy loading of the classes.
>   Means classes are loaded as they are required directly OR INDIRECTLY.